# How to pass enum type to lambda

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I've got a this function interface:

```
public static interface RotationDirectionCorectorGetter<MountingLocation extends Enum<MountingLocation>> {
    public Map<MountingLocation, Boolean> getModuleRotationDirectionCorrections(Map<MountingLocation, ModuleRotationVectors> rotationDirections);
}
```

Now i'd like to create an instance of it with a function that looks like this:

```
public static <MountingLocation extends Enum<MountingLocation>> Map<MountingLocation, Boolean> getModuleRotaionDirectionCorrections(
        Map<MountingLocation, ModuleRotationVectors> rotationDirections, boolean isRobotRotating) {
}
```

My first try was this, `MountingLocations` is an enum that exist localy in the same class:

```
RotationDirectionCorectorGetter<MountingLocations> directionCorectorGetter = (Map<MountingLocations, ModuleRotationVectors> rotationDirections) -> getModuleRotaionDirectionCorrections<MountingLocations>(rotationDirections);
```

Eventualy this doesn't work, vscode sais:

> getModuleRotaionDirectionCorrections cannot be resolved or is not a
> field

What would be the correct syntax to do this or is this not even posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made just a dum mistake i didn't remamber that the function also takes a boolean and not just a map. For general to this question, you don't have to specify the generic in the function that you're calling in the lambda so the solution looks like this:

```
RotationDirectionCorectorGetter<MountingLocations> directionCorectorGetter = (Map<MountingLocations, ModuleRotationVectors> rotationDirections) -> getModuleRotaionDirectionCorrections(rotationDirections, true);
```